# I am using undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am using `undetected_chromedriver`, but I am getting the error

```
This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
Current browser version is 103.0.5060.53
```

My code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc 
uc.TARGET_VERSION = 103 
options = uc.ChromeOptions()    
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') 
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, version_main=103, patcher_force_close=True) 
driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl') 
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)'s UC Mode to use undetected-chromedriver with any browser version (it automatically downloads the correct driver if missing).

First `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True, incognito=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
time.sleep(8)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: So I don't need to use undetected_chromedriver?

Comment: You don't need to use ``undetected-chromedriver`` directly because ``seleniumbase`` includes it with patches.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask, is the syntax for manipulating web page elements similar to selenium?

Comment: You can use ``driver`` just as you would with regular ``selenium``. But there are other syntax formats you can use (https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/syntax_formats.md) which include more methods, and integration with ``pytest``, etc.

Comment: In Selenium, I often use the following code to set the debugger address:

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", debugger_address)
To achieve the same in SeleniumBase, how should I do it?

Comment: On https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager.py, scroll down to the definition of `Driver()` and see all the available args that you can set.

Comment: @MichaelMintz how can I pass `disable-dev-shm-usage` to `Driver()`?

Comment: `disable-dev-shm-usage` is already included automatically